# Извлечь элемент из списка в одной строке, в нужном порядке

Tags: sql, oracle

Задам вопрос в форме упрощенной задачи от реального случая.

Дано: таблица tab_1 со столбцом col_1 строкового типа, в котором есть перечисление элементов. В качестве примера возьмем:

```
WITH tab_1
     AS (SELECT '4,5,44,46,3' col_1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT '7,44'        col_1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT '67,32,5'     col_1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT '26,34,44'    col_1 FROM DUAL)
SELECT col_1
  FROM tab_1;
```

Наша задача: из каждой строки в столбце col_1 извлечь только один элемент, который также входит в контрольный список '32,34,5,44'. Если в строке есть два элемента из контрольного списка, то взять тот, что приоритетнее (приоритет такой же 32,34,5,44). Ожидаемый ответ:

```
 | result_val |
 |------------|
 |      5     |
 |     44     |
 |     32     |
 |     34     |
```

Вопрос: какой запрос следует сделать из tab_1?

Comment: Через REGEXP_LIKE только удалось фильтрануть нужные строки, поэтому в целом мы уверены, что в каждой строке будет хоть оди из нужных элементов, но как красиво теперь распарсить и вытянуть наиболее приоритетный - голову уже сломал.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303

Comment: @Akina, я немного огорчен, что вы решили, что мне хватит компетенций чтобы решить задачу по одному упоминанию функции, но не хватает чтобы быть в курсе существования этой функции. Задачу решил, завтра выложу ответ. Помимо регулярки потребуется еще рекурсивный запрос и пара группировок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось такое решение в контексте поставленной задачи. Характерно, что здесь задействован сплит строк через регулярное выражение, но именно всех строк в наборе (а не как в большинстве вопросов на stackoverflow только одной строки на манер функции).

```
WITH tab_1
     AS (SELECT '4,5,44,46,3' col_1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT '7,44'        col_1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT '67,32,5'     col_1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT '26,34,44'    col_1 FROM DUAL)
SELECT col_1
     , CASE MAX(CASE parts
                    WHEN '32' THEN 4
                    WHEN '34' THEN 3
                    WHEN '5' THEN 2
                    WHEN '44' THEN 1
                    ELSE -1
                END)
           WHEN 4 THEN 32
           WHEN 3 THEN 34
           WHEN 2 THEN 5
           WHEN 1 THEN 44
           ELSE -1
       END
           result_val
  FROM (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.col_1, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS parts
                 , t.*
              FROM tab_1 t
        CONNECT BY PRIOR t.col_1 = t.col_1
               AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
               AND LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT(t.col_1, '([^,]*)(,|$)'))
 GROUP BY col_1;
```